# What is an "XCopy version"?

Tags: oracle, xcopy

I am trying to download Oracle Data Access Components. Some of the components are named as `XCopy version`. I know that [XCopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY) is a command but what exactly does it mean in this context ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

it appears to be referring to the same [`Xcopy` command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx) you are, and will do an [Xcopy deployment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY_deployment), instead of using OUI. From the documentation ([this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/win.121/e17732/InstallODP.htm#ODPNT151), for example):

> Administrators use XCopy to deploy Oracle Data Provider for .NET to
>   large numbers of computers for production deployments. The XCopy has a
>   smaller installation size and fine-grain control during installation
>   and configuration than Oracle Universal Installer.

The `install.bat` for the [12c ODAC installer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html) is doing:

```
xcopy asp.net %2 /E /F /R /Y >> %2\install.log
```

etc., for each component, where `%2` is the path supplied to the installer, e.g. `c:\oracle`.