# Connecting to Oracle database from Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Our organization has a Windows server running SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS).  We use SSRS to build reports that access an Oracle database.  We were able to get SSRS to connect to our Oracle database by installing [Oracle Data Access Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html) (ODAC) for Windows on our server.  We installed the [Xcopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19949720/what-is-an-xcopy-version) versions - both 32-bit and 64-bit (don't know if we needed to do both; SSRS used to only accept 32-bit drivers).  We were able to successfully set up a data source in SSRS that connected to the Oracle database.

However, we write our reports on development machines using SQL Server Report Builder 3.0.  When building a report that uses a shared data source on the server - the one that accesses our Oracle database, we get the error

> The selected data extension ORACLE is not installed or cannot be loaded...

What do we need to do to be able to write reports from our development machines that use a shared data source to our Oracle database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install ODAC on your development machines as well.  Even though you are configuring your report to use a shared data source on the server, Report Builder 3.0 will use connection drivers on the local machine to build and preview report data.

Report Builder 3.0 still seems to be a 32-bit application (as of 6/3/2016), so you only need to install 32-bit ODAC package.

Comment: Read the readme.htm file that comes with ODAC for instructions on how to install.  We tried to be selective about which specific ODAC products to install, but weren't able to find which ones we needed and which ones we didn't.   So we just ended up installing all the products, i.e. `install.bat all c:\oracle odac`